# Catching mysqli_sql_exception on CLI commands from Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, exception, codeigniter-4

so I'm using Codeigniter 4 to power the API server for one of my company's system. Recently we've found some issues whereby backend CLI processes (managed by PM2) that run on a loop would start generating loads of "mysql has gone away" exceptions without terminating the process whenever mysql is restarting or facing some issues (this is on a test server which shares resources across many projects). What I've tried is to do a `$db->reconnect();` in a try-catch block before each loop is called and this worked to reconnect once mysql has recovered without the test failing or exiting but it also proved to be highly inefficient as the connection was being dropped and connected again. With 7 processes running at intervals of between 1-10s each, it is a lot of reconnects.

Here's a snippet of the original code before applying the reconnect function:

```
// file: app/Commands/IntervalProcess.php
abstract class IntervalProcess extends BaseCommand
{
    // some CI command variables here
    // some process management variables & functions
    // (e.g. $running, $sleep, shutdown(), pcntl_signal(), etc.)
    public function run(array $params)
    {
        while ($running) {
            $this->execute();
            usleep($sleep * 1000000);
        }
    }
    
    abstract protected function execute();
}
```

```
// file: app/Commands/InitAction.php
class InitAction extends IntervalProcess
{
    // some CI command variables here (overriding from abstract class)
    protected function execute()
    {
        $actionModel = new ActionModel(); //extends Model (from CI)
        $actions = $actionModel->where('status', 1)->findAll();
        
        foreach ($actions as $action) {
            //do some magical actions
        }
    }
}
```

The exceptions originates from the `ActionModel` when mysql fails.

The next thing I tried is to embed the `$this->execute();` in a try-catch block and trying to catch the `mysqli_sql_exception` or even the whole `Exception` but it is unable to catch any exceptions and will stay in the loop, generating endless errors in the logs.

Ideally, what I need is either 1) catch the exception and try to reconnect to the DB or 2) force the CLI command to exit so PM2 will automatically start it again until mysql has recovered.

Appreciate any help to get this sorted.